# vsftpd with virtual users and independent directory configuration

Tags: linux, permissions, chmod, vsftpd

I followed the nice tutorial from https://askubuntu.com/questions/575523/how-to-setup-virtual-users-for-vsftpd-with-access-to-a-specific-sub-directory

Now If I understood I have 2 things:

1) one is the only user called **`vsftpd`** that acts as dedicated-user for the vsftpd service

2) is the capability of creating users specific configurations under the **`/etc/vsftpd_user_conf/`** folder

so I can have a **`/etc/vsftpd_user_conf/user1`** file maybe filled with:

```
local_root=/var/www/website_name1/sub_folder1
```

a **`/etc/vsftpd_user_conf/user2`** with specific

```
local_root=/var/www/website_name1/sub_folder2
```

and so on..

---

With this setup I can set the main or the sub_folders inside their roots and make them writable by assigning or not the chmod vsftpd:nogroup and the common 777, 775 or 664 common attributes.

---

But I would like to create a more complex setup.

I would like to create a folder:

**`/var/ftp_users/`**

with

```
/var/ftp_users/boss
/var/ftp_users/employee1
/var/ftp_users/employee2
/var/ftp_users/employee3
...
```

In order to make them accessible and writable I will have to

```
chmod vsftpd:nogroup /var/ftp_users/boss
chmod vsftpd:nogroup /var/ftp_users/employee1
chmod vsftpd:nogroup /var/ftp_users/employee2
...
```

and also set their local root as follows:

`/etc/vsftpd_user_conf/employee1` with `local_root=/var/ftp_users/employee1`
`/etc/vsftpd_user_conf/employee2` with `local_root=/var/ftp_users/employee2`
`/etc/vsftpd_user_conf/employee3` with `local_root=/var/ftp_users/employee3`
...

The problem is that BOSS asked me to:

- **being able to read everyone folders so that he can see what other users are doing. My idea was to put his `local_root=/var/ftp_users`**
- **BUT -- I want that boss to be able to write/modify only `/var/ftp_users/boss` and not everyone other folders, create new ones or delete the ones he found inside !**

How is it possible in this setup so that user boss has `local_root=/var/ftp_users` BUT its write access is only limited to `/var/ftp_users/boss` ?

I also considered manually create symlinks inside

```
ln /var/ftp_users/employee1 /var/ftp_users/boss/employee1
```

and

```
chmod -h 0444 /var/ftp_users/boss/employee1
```

but this way is not working properly.

I'm used to the Windows permissions or the directives you can specify inside Apache, nginx and so on, so I'm a bit lost with vsftpd config. Under normal circumstances I would have set the **`/var/ftp_users/`** root non writable and only the **`/var/ftp_users/boss`** folder writable.